# SwiftyJSON.JSON to [String: AnyObject]

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

How can i make `[String: AnyObject]` from `JSON`?

```
let jsonString = Mapper().toJSONString(article!)

// {\"price\":\"220.00\",\"name\":\"Capricciosa\",\"active\":true,\"calculable\":true,\"id\":76,\"article_type\":2,\"ingredients\":[],\"critical_qty\":\"0.00\",\"barcode\":\"\",\"tax\":\"1\"}


let json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(jsonString!)
// i need here to get [String: AnyObject]
```

need this for `Alamofire` parametres..

Answer (score 4):

You can access the `dictionaryObject` direct from the SwiftyJSON `json`

```
    let dict: [String: AnyObject]
    if jDict = json.dictionaryObject {
        dict = jDict
    } else {
        dict = [String: AnyObject]()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
    let jsonString = "{\"price\":\"220.00\",\"name\":\"Capricciosa\",\"active\":true,\"calculable\":true,\"id\":76,\"article_type\":2,\"ingredients\":[],\"critical_qty\":\"0.00\",\"barcode\":\"\",\"tax\":\"1\"}"
    var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
    if let dataFromString = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
        let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
        for (key, value) : (String, JSON) in json {
            dict[key] = value.object
        }
    }
```

Comment: It returns `nil` for first two solutions, and `[:]` for `dictionaryValue`.

Answer (score 2):

SwiftyJSON is actually just a wrapper around the `NSJSONSerialization` in Foundation, it just makes it more convenient to access the values and dig down in the structure. However that's not what you actually want to do, you only need the dictionary which is just what `NSJSONSerialization` returns. If you'd use SwiftyJSON for that, you'd just be taking the long route.

This function does what you need without SwiftyJSON:

```
func jsonDict(json: String) -> [String : AnyObject]? {
    if let
        data = json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
        object = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []),
        dict = object as? [String : AnyObject] {
            return dict
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer a more functional approach:

```
func jsonDict(json: String) -> [String : AnyObject]? {
    return json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        .flatMap{ try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData($0, options: []) }
        .flatMap{ $0 as? [String : AnyObject] }
}
```